# Xamarin Forms convert Xaml to common resource style Yummy PancakeView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to convert my properties of a pancake control into a style so all my pancake controls are styled the same.  This is what my XAML looks like.

```
    <yummy:PancakeView x:Name="pvMEssage" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource ExceptionBackground}" CornerRadius="0,0,20,20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <yummy:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,0">
            <yummy:GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="{DynamicResource ExceptionBackground}" />
        </yummy:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>
        <yummy:PancakeView.Border>
            <yummy:Border Color="White" Thickness="2" />
        </yummy:PancakeView.Border>
```

I know how to use setter.value in a style but I cannot figure out how to put the backgroundgradientstops in the style.

I have this so far:

```
            <Style x:Key="PancakeViewTop" TargetType="yummy:PancakeView">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20,20,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundGradientStartPoint" Value="0,0" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundGradientEndPoint" Value="0,0" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundGradientStops">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <yummy:GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="{DynamicResource ExceptionBackground}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <yummy:Border Color="White" Thickness="2" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

but I get an error on these lines

```
<Setter Property="BackgroundGradientStops">
    <Setter.Value>
```

that states "The specified value cannot be assigned.  The following type was expected: "GradientStopCollection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
<Setter Property="BackgroundGradientStops">
    <Setter.Value>
        <pancake:GradientStopCollection>
            <pancake:GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="{DynamicResource ExceptionBackground}"/>
            <pancake:GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{DynamicResource OtherColor}"/>
        </pancake:GradientStopCollection>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Also you need to specify at least 2 colors (2 `GradientStop`) otherwise it will throw an exception

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'needs >= 2 number of colors'

and it does not make sens a gradient with only one color.

Comment: Well it does make sense to do one color s I am only doing this to address a defect in the pancake control on UWP where the background color is not being clipped to the bounds on the rounded corners.  This work around is documented in the issues for the pancake control in their github project.  The rest I will try and see if it works and post back.  Thank you.

Comment: Good you can post the link to this issue in comment maybe can be useful for someone.

Comment: Here is the link to the issue with a workaround provided:  https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView/issues/150